Graphs $G$ with $G \cong \text{Aut}(G)$
Let $G=(V,E)$ be a simple, undirected graph. By $\newcommand{\Aut}{\text{Aut}}\Aut(G)$ we denote the collection of graph isomorphisms $\varphi:G\to G$. We let $$E(\Aut(G)) =\big\{\{\varphi, \psi\}:\varphi, \psi \in \Aut(G)\text{ and } \{\varphi(v),\psi(v)\}\in E\text{ for all }v\in V\big\}.$$ So $\big(\Aut(G), E(\Aut(G)\big)$ is a simple, undirected graph.
Question. If $\kappa$ is a cardinal, is there a connected graph $G=(V,E)$ with $|V|\geq \kappa$ and $G \cong \Aut(G)$?

It seems that the adjacency graph on the integers is a countably infinite instance, but I don't yet see how to make uncountable instances.

There is also $x\mapsto -x$. Thus $Aut(\mathbb{Z})$ should have two components.

Ah, darn. You are right. So do we have any examples?

I only see the graph with one vertex.

and the graph with two vertices and no edge.

He wants a connected graph. But in light of the paucity of examples, any $G$ with $G\cong \text{Aut}(G)$ is interesting.

@JoelDavidHamkins The complete graph $K_2$ is a (trivial) connected example.

@DominicvanderZypen $K_3$ is not, $\text{Aut} (K_3)$ has $2$ components, both isomorphic to $K_3$.

@Zerox Right, thanks, I also realized it and deleted my comment. So "it looks like" (for what it's worth) that there are no connected examples of connected graphs $G$ with more than $2$ points and $G\cong\text{Aut}(G)$

One simple observation: for any $\newcommand{\Aut}{\mathrm{Aut}}G$, $\Aut(G)$ is always vertex-transitive, since for any $f, g$, left-multiplication by $gf^{-1}$ is an automorphism sending $f$ to $g$.  So if $G \simeq \Aut(G)$, then $G$ must be vertex-transitive, for starters.

Thanks @bof for your observation - I will correct this!

I will prove that if $G \cong \mathrm{Aut}(G)$ and $G$ is finite, then $G$ is the Cayley graph of a commutative group of exponent $2$. Then with Godsil's theorem about the existence of graphical regular representation (see page 32 of this, sadly I have no access to the original paper) there are examples with arbitrary large finite cardinals.
Let's denote $Q(G)$ the automorphism group of any graph $G$. Then $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ is a graph with vertices indexed by $Q(G)$. Suppose $G \cong \mathrm{Aut}(G)$, one has $\mathrm{Aut}(G) \cong \mathrm{Aut}(\mathrm{Aut}(G))$. However, in $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathrm{Aut}(G))$, $2$ types of vertices can be found:
1. The left translations $\{l_g: \varphi \mapsto g\varphi \mid g \in Q(G)\}$. Given $g \in Q(G)$, $l_g$ is clearly a bijection on $V(\mathrm{Aut}(G))$. To see it also respects adjacency, observe that $$\{\varphi, \psi\} \in E(\mathrm{Aut}(G)) \implies \forall v \in V, \{\varphi(v), \psi(v)\}\in E \overset{g \in Q(G)}{\implies} \forall v \in V, \{g\varphi(v), g\psi(v)\}\in E \implies \{g\varphi, g\psi\}=l_g\{\varphi, \psi\} \in E(\mathrm{Aut}(G))$$
One can also get that $$\{\varphi, \psi\} \in E(\mathrm{Aut}(G)) \iff \forall v \in V, \{\varphi(v), \psi(v)\} \in E \iff \forall v \in V, g \in Q(G), \{\varphi g(v), \psi g(v)\} \in E \iff \forall g \in Q(G)=V(\mathrm{Aut}(G)), \{\varphi g, \psi g\}= \{l_\varphi(g), l_\psi(g)\} \in E \iff \{l_\varphi, l_\psi\} \in E(\mathrm{Aut}(\mathrm{Aut}(G)))$$
Therefore, the induced subgraph $L(G)$ of $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathrm{Aut}(G))$ with vertices $\{l_g\}$ is isomorphic to $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$.
2. The right translations $\{r_g^{-1}: \varphi \mapsto \varphi g \mid g \in Q(G)\}$. Given $g \in Q(G)$, $r_g^{-1}$ is clearly a bijection on $V(\mathrm{Aut}(G))$. To see it also respects adjacency, observe that $$\{\varphi, \psi\} \in E(\mathrm{Aut}(G)) \implies \forall v \in V, \{\varphi(v), \psi(v)\}\in E \overset{g \in Q(G)}{\implies} \forall v \in V, \{\varphi g(v), \psi g(v)\}\in E \implies \{\varphi g, \psi g\}=r_g^{-1}\{\varphi, \psi\} \in E(\mathrm{Aut}(G))$$
One can also get that $$\{\varphi, \psi\} \in E(\mathrm{Aut}(G)) \iff \forall v \in V, \{\varphi(v), \psi(v)\} \in E \iff \forall v \in V, g \in Q(G), \{g\varphi(v), g\psi(v)\} \in E \iff \forall g \in Q(G)=V(\mathrm{Aut}(G)), \{g\varphi, g\psi\}= \{r_\varphi^{-1}(g), r_\psi^{-1}(g)\} \in E \iff \{r_\varphi^{-1}, r_\psi^{-1}\} \in E(\mathrm{Aut}(\mathrm{Aut}(G)))$$
Therefore, the induced subgraph $R(G)$ of $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathrm{Aut}(G))$ with vertices $\{r_g^{-1}\}$ is also isomorphic to $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$.
When $G$ is a finite graph, the statement above immediately implies that $L(G) = R(G) = \mathrm{Aut}(\mathrm{Aut}(G)) \cong \mathrm{Aut}(G)$. Considering the image of $e \in Q(G) = V(\mathrm{Aut}(G))$ under the action of $Q(\mathrm{Aut}(G))$, one must have $l_g = r_g^{-1}$ in $Q(\mathrm{Aut}(G)) \cong Q(G)$, which means that $Q(G)$ is commutative.
Denote the set of vertices adjacent to $e$ by $S \subseteq Q(G)$, then since $\{l_g\}$ respects adjacency, the connected component of $e$ in $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ is the Cayley graph of the group generated by $S$. Connectedness of $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ implies that $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ is the Cayley graph of the commutative group $Q(G)$ with generators $S$. $S$ is clearly symmetric: $\{e,g\} \in E(\mathrm{Aut}(G)) \implies l_{g^{-1}}\{e,g\} = \{g^{-1},e\} \in E(\mathrm{Aut}(G))$.
If $Q(G)$ is not of exponent $2$, then an element in $S$ must have order $k \ne 2$. Thus $g \mapsto g^{-1}$ is a non-trivial automorphism of $\mathrm{Aut}(G) = \mathrm{Cay}(Q(G),S)$ that is not of the form $\{l_g\}$, contradicting $L(G) = \mathrm{Aut}(G)$. The claim then follows.

I don’t quite follow the step “Consider the image of the vertex indexed by $e \in Q(G)$ one must have $l_g = r^{-1}_g$.”  At this point we have several different maps between graphs in play — you mean “the image” under which map, and “indexed by” under which map?  And is $g$ meant to be that specific vertex, or a general element of $Q(G)$?

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Sine $L(G) = R(G)$, they have the same vertices in $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathrm{Aut}(G))$. So we must have $\forall g \in Q(G), \exists h \in Q(G), l_g = r_h^{-1}$ in the group $Q(\mathrm{Aut}(G))$. Then $l_g(e) = r_h^{-1}(e)$ as vertex in $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$.

Aha, right — that makes sense!

At least the claim “every element of $\newcommand{\Aut}{\mathrm{Aut}}\Aut(G)$ must have order 2” still holds, if I’m not mistaken.  Once we know every automorphism is of the form $l_g$, any automorphism of $\Aut(G)$ that fixes $e$ must be the identity; in particular the “inversion” automorphism $f \mapsto f^{-1}$ must be the identity, i.e. every element of $\Aut(G)$ is of order 2.

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Thanks. By the way, do you think the Cayley graph of $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^4$ with generators ${a,b,c,d,a+b,a+c,a+b+c,a+b+d}$ satisfies $G \cong \mathrm{Aut}(G)$?

Thanks for this nice effort @Zerox ! Nice that Cayley graphs are coming in

I am still a bit confused. The Cayley-graph is usually an directed graph, and here we are looking at undirected graphs. Since all generators have order 2, we get for each edge in the directed version also an edge backwards. I assume these form together one undirected edge and this change does not affect the automorphism groups of the graphs.

@HenrikRüping When the generating set $S$ is symmetric ($S = S^{-1}$), the Cayley graph can be represented as a simple undirected graph. Godsil's theorem deals with both the directed case and the undirected simple case.
